# Yii CActiveDataProvider filter by date range criteria

Tags: database, yii, criteria

I'm working with Yii 1.1.8. Trying to limit the $dataProvider source by date in a controller action. I want to filter the dataset to show only the recent 2 year entries, but couldn't get it to work.

I got two records in the Event table where one is dated 2 months ago and the other is dated 4 years ago.

Tried:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Event', array(
                    'criteria'=>array(
                        'condition'=>'date >= '.date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-2 years')). ' AND  date <='. date('Y-m-d'),
                    ),
                ));
```

and

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Event', array(
                    'criteria'=>array(
                        'condition'=>'date >= '.date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-2 years')),
                    ),
                ));
```

and

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Event', array(
                    'criteria'=>array(
                        'condition'=>'date BETWEEN '.date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-2 years')).' AND '. date('Y-m-d'),
                    ),
                ));
```

All returned with "No results found". What am I doing wrong? It seems it should be something simple, but I'm stumped.

Comment: it is indeed something simple. I missed the quotation marks… 'condition'=>'date >= "'.date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-2 years')).'"', works

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's easier to create a new CDbCriteria and then pass the criteria object into the second param of the CActiveDataProvider.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addBetweenCondition-detail

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria; 
$criteria->addBetweenCondition($column, $valueStart, $valueEnd, 'AND');

$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Event', array('criteria'=>$criteria));
```

Comment: I am trying this but its not working for me. I have a date field in the db called `last_updated` now i want to compare using between 2 dates. How would i complete the `_search.php` page to incorporate this?

Comment: You will need to add new inputs to the search page, then pass those values into the method below.
...
    $criteria->addBetweenCondition('last_updated', $_POST['valueStart'], $_POST['valueEnd'], 'AND');

If you are using pagination, make sure you set the form method to 'GET'

Answer (score 0):

You have a quotation problem there; the dates should be included in single quotes.
Try this:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Event', array(
                   'criteria'=>array(
                            'condition'=>"date BETWEEN '".date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-2 years'))."' AND '" . date('Y-m-d') . "'",
                        ),
                    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use to:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->condition = "date_start >= '$date_start' AND date_end <= '$date_end'";
$model = TemporadaAlta::model()->find($criteria);
```